# Can we use If...else conditions in Robotium scripting? Please give any example

Tags: robotium

I have may flows where I have to use if..else condtions. please provide me the brief idea how to use is.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Button answer_a = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.answer_a);
        Button answer_b = (Button) solo.getView(R.id.answer_b);
        if (answer_a.getText().toString().equals("my_text_a")) {
            solo.clickOnView(answer_a);
        } else {
            solo.clickOnView(answer_b);
        }
```